# How to get the rendered size of a visual in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a situation where I need to get the rendered size of a visual element on WPF. I mean, I need to get the space that something consumes on the visual space, like a `Button` with a `DropShadowEffect` applied and not just the values of  `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties.

As an example, consider the following scenario:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100">
    <Button.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0"/>
    </Button.Effect>
</Button>
```

As you can see, the button has a size of 100x100, but because it has a drop shadow with a blur radius of 10, it needs 120x120 of rendering space.

How would I get the rendered size of this button (which is 120x120) in WPF?

There is already another similar question on StackOverflow, but it didn't get an exact answer. So I'm asking this question.

---

### Additional details about what I'm trying to achieve

The situation where I need this is the following:

I need to extend the visual frame of a custom window to outside of the window's bounds. To achieve that I'm using 4 other adjacent windows around the actual window's bounds. In each of this adjacent window, I display a `VisualBrush` that displays the content that would be displayed outside of a window (like a drop shadow), just like it would on a normal control. But to know the exact size to apply to each adjacent window and to make the `VisualBrush`'s content to be displayed aligned with the main window content, I need at least to know the size and the position of the content.

Probably, maybe there is another way of achieving this...

Comment: The extra windows seem like they would just complicate things to me.  Wouldn't it much more simple for you to use a `DockPanel` with your "extensions" as elements docked top, left, right, and bottom, with the actual content docked to fill the center?  This way everything is contained in one window that automatically grows to whatever size is required to fit both the content, and the effects, you never need to worry about the actual size of things like the shadow.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Well, I tried different approaches to achieve a draw-out-of-bounds feature. Using additional "ghost" windows is, for me, what is achieving the best results so far. The user is unaware of those additional windows and everything works as expected from the shell point of view. I think it is like Visual Studio does for its blur effect around its window.

Answer (score 1):

The way I could find is to use the `VisualTreeHelper.GetEffect` method, get the effect associated with the visual, then do some manual calculations based on the type of the attached effect.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.geteffect(v=vs.110).aspx